# Use Office 2003 interop DLLs without installing the redistributable

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am writing a C# program (.net 2.0) that needs to read excel files. I came to know that I will have to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. I downloaded `O2003PIA.MSI` and using 7Zip, extraced the DLLs(didn't install). Now, when I add reference to the extracted `EXCELPIA.DLL`, it throws the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I want to deploy the assemblies as private assemblies and does not want the end user to install the Redistributable.  Are there any dependnecies I am missing ?

I already tried adding reference to `OFFICE.DLL` but it does not help either.

**EDIT 1**

1. Is it required to install Office 2003 before using this ?
2. Is there any other .net 2.0 alternative ?

Comment: The PIAs are only wrappers: use "dependency viewer" to see if there are any missing prerequisite DLLs. These DLLs must be found *while loading* the assembly (i.e. in searchable DLL paths) but *should not* be added as project references. Remember that the respective Office programs installed to use the PIAs. Also, make sure to target the correct bitness only (32-bit for Office 2003) as a 64-bit executable will fail to find the correct 32-bit resources.

Comment: I used Dependency Walker and found that it depends on MSCOREE.dll

Comment: That is indeed part of Office :) I do not know if it is possible to obtain/distribute such files *without* installing Office, however. (Also verify VS is running in 32-bit mode if Office is installed; 64-bit Office support didn't come until Office 2007.)

Comment: I dont have office 2003 installed nor I can. Any alternatives than office interop to read excel file cells ?

Comment: A third-party library. Search on stackoverflow, codeplex, and google - there is at least one free/open-license library that targets pre-2007 Excel formats - e.g http://excellite.codeplex.com/ (others?) There are also some Java libraries, so via a *round-about* method, those could also be an option.

Comment: ExcelLite also requires Office to be installed. What I ned it: Dont want to install Office and stick to .net 2.0 only.

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful but for Office 2007+ files (xlsx) Microsoft produce the OpenXml SDK ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824.aspx ) which will allow you to read / write without the dependency on Office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a thing called [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) and it worked just fine.